# Не отвечает на команду

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

При команде `/reg` бот должен спросить имя. Вместо этого ничего. Даже не запоминает имя.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['reg', 'Reg'])
def echo_all(message):
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "»Вы хотите зарегистрироваться? Отлично! Как вас зовут?")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_name)

def reg_name(message):
    global name
    name = message.text

#Клавиатура
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    key_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = "да", callback_data = "yes")
    keyboard.add(key_yes)
    key_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = "нет", callback_data = "no")
    keyboard.add(key_no)
    question = "»вас зовут "+name+" ?"
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text= question, reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == "yes":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "»приятно познакомиться "+name+"!")
    elif call.data == "no":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "»попробуйте ещё раз!")
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "»Вы хотите зрагеестрироваться? Отлично! Как вас зовут?")
```

Comment: При просмотре кода у меня возник вопрос, text= question, у вас есть переменная question из тектсом? Если нет, то возможно в этом и ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл проблему почти сразу. Сначало стояло так: {name}.

```
hi_otvet = ["Приветик "+name+" ", "Здраствуйте "+name+" "]
```

Comment: если у вас было `{name}`, то это похоже на применение `f-строки`: `f'привет {name}'`

Answer (score 1):

[step_example.py#L24](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/b45db584df86db7f7d08329be8bdcd2420a2b62d/examples/step_example.py#L24)

`bot.register_next_step_handler` принимает минимум два аргумента сообщение которое нужно отправить и функция к которой нужно перейти.
определите отправку сообщения как `msg`, например.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['reg', 'Reg'])
def echo_all(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "»Вы хотите зарегестрироваться? Отлично! Как вас зовут?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, reg_name)
```